# String.length() doesn't work for "Rolling On the Floor Laughing" : ?

Tags: java, utf-8

I'm trying to print the first 30 characters of some UTF-8 strings, and notice that Java's `String.substring()` is returning some funky strings. I've boiled it down to:

I'm expecting "" to be String with length 1, and `String.substring` to not try to cut it over in the middle. Why is my expectation not met? Java thinks it has length 2.

I'm pretty sure ([1](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+1F923) [2](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f923/index.htm)) the UTF-8 encoding for   (U+1F923) "Rolling On the Floor Laughing" is:

```
0xF0 0x9F 0xA4 0xA3
```

And so I expect this tiny program:

```java
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class Foo {

  public static void main(String[] args){
    String str = "";
    // These are the UTF-8 bytes for "ROLLING ON THE FLOOR LAUGHING"
    byte[] raw = {(byte)0xf0, (byte)0x9f, (byte)0xa4, (byte)0xa3};
    String str2 = new String(raw, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    System.out.println(str.equals(str2));
    System.out.println(str.length());
    System.out.println(str.substring(0,1));
  }
}
```

To print out:

```
true
1
```

But in fact it prints out:

```
true
2
?
```

Am I doing something wrong?

I've tried an custom java 11.0.20.1 build and these standard Ubuntu packages with the same results:

```
$ javac -version
javac 19.0.2

$ java -version
openjdk version "19.0.2" 2023-01-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 19.0.2+7-Ubuntu-0ubuntu322.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.0.2+7-Ubuntu-0ubuntu322.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

python3 does what I expect:

```bash
$ python3 -c 'print(len(""))'
1

$ python3 -c 'print(""[0])'
```

Comment: Maybe your Java see surrogates (0xd83e,0xdd23) of `` U+1F923, *ROLLING ON THE FLOOR LAUGHING (0xd83e,0xdd23)*?

Comment: Essentially Java strings have been "broken using old API calls" (for some strings) for a while, since characters broke the `char` barrier some time ago. You need, for 'completeness' and accuracy, always to consider codepoints now, rather than chars. So `System.out.printf("String '%s' has length %d%n", str, str.codePoints().count());` is going to report the true state of affairs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java stores strings as UTF-16 encoded (or close to).  takes up two UTF-16 code units (0xd83e, 0xdd23). Hence the reason why its length is 2 and the first UTF-16 code unit on its own doesn't make any sense.

The Java string functions work on individual UTF-16 code units, not full Unicode characters.

Comment: Ok, how do I then get the number of "full Unicode characters" in a string, and *safely* get the first 30 *characters* of a string? - apparently not with `String.length()` and `String.stubstring()`. (Requesting for me to open a separate question is also ok.)

Comment: @PeterV.Mørch I don't know. You could scan the string. The double characters are easy to spot because the first one will be in the range 0xD800–0xDBFF and the second will be in the range 0xDC00-0xDFFF. But even that is not fool proof. Generally, doing Unicode properly is hard.

Comment: @PeterV.Mørch It depends on what you mean by "full Unicode characters". If you mean a Unicode code point, use `yourString.codePoints().count()`. If you mean a grapheme cluster, use a `BreakIterator` to count. For example, do you count  as one character?

Comment: Technical terminology nit: A Unicode code *point* is made up of one or two UTF-16 code *units*

Comment: @MarkTolonen Thanks for the correction. I always get the terminology mixed up.

Comment: And a Unicode "grapheme cluster" (what people usually think of as a "character") is made up of one or more code *points* acting together to make up a single visual symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Since what I really wanted was the first N "chars" of a string, I'll post a solution here for that. But since that isn't reflected in the question title, I'll accept the other answer, even though this is what I ended up using:

```java
import java.text.BreakIterator;

public class Foo {

  public static String utf8SafeStringPrefix(String input, int nChars) {
    return input
        .codePoints()
        .limit(nChars)
        .mapToObj(Character::toString)
        .collect(Collectors.joining());
  }

  // This was the previous version from before g00se kindly offered his shorter version above
  public static String utf8SafeStringPrefixUsingBreakIterator(String input, int numPrefixCodepoints) {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(input.length());
    BreakIterator it = BreakIterator.getCharacterInstance();
    it.setText(input);
    int start = it.first();
    int end = it.next();

    int numAppendedCodepoints = 0;
    while (end != BreakIterator.DONE) {
      String codepoint = input.substring(start, end);
      stringBuilder.append(codepoint);
      numAppendedCodepoints++;
      if (numAppendedCodepoints == numPrefixCodepoints) {
        break;
      }
      start = end;
      end = it.next();
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "this-is-a--character";
    System.out.println(utf8SafeStringPrefix(str, 10));
    System.out.println(utf8SafeStringPrefix(str, 11));
    System.out.println(utf8SafeStringPrefix(str, 12));
  }
}
```

Which prints out:

```
this-is-a-
this-is-a-
this-is-a--
```

Comment: That's good, but probably simpler to do: `public static String utf8SafeStringPrefix(String s, int nChars) {return s.codePoints().limit(nChars).mapToObj(Character::toString).collect(Collectors.joining());}`

Comment: @g00se: Thanks - I've updated my answer to use your solution.

Comment: String.codePoints() is only in Java 9+.

Comment: True, but that version is already old ;) Still, it's nice to see `BreakIterator`, which is like seeing a white tiger

Comment: Note that cutting exactly at Unicode codepoint separations can actually change the content of a string. Cutting of `x = "\u0061\u0308"` renders as `ä` but taking just the first codepoint produces `a`. Similarly ‍♂️ will transform into  ... The `BreakIterator` approach will handle both of those correctly!